# RxAndroid called from main thread

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I have this issue ;)

I'm trying to call this usecase, which at the end returns an Observable.

But, despite using schedulers, constantly is being invoked on the main thread. I don't know why:

It looks like this:

```
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(private val loadNewsUseCase: LoadNews) : Model {

    override fun loadNews() {
        loadNewsUseCase.execute(NewsObserver(), "")
    }

    override fun dispose() {
        loadNewsUseCase.dispose()
    }
}

class NewsObserver : DisposableObserver<Result>() {
    override fun onComplete() {
        Log.i("TAG", "")
    }

    override fun onNext(t: Result) {
        Log.i("TAG", "")

    }

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        Log.i("TAG", "")

    }
}
```

-

```
abstract class UseCase<T, in P>(
        private val computationThreadExecutor: ComputationThreadExecutor,
        private val mainThreadExecutor: MainThreadExecutor,
        private val compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
) {

    abstract fun createUseCase(params: P): Observable<T>

    fun execute(disposableObserver: DisposableObserver<T>, params: P) {
        requireNotNull(disposableObserver)

        val observable = createUseCase(params)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(mainThreadExecutor.getThread())

        val disposable = observable.subscribeWith(disposableObserver)

        addDisposable(disposable)
    }

    private fun addDisposable(disposable: Disposable) {
        requireNotNull(disposable)
        compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
    }

    fun dispose() {
        !compositeDisposable.isDisposed.apply { compositeDisposable.dispose() }
    }
}
```

UseCase concrete implementation uses DataService to fetch data from api, which looks like this:

```
open class NewsDataService(private val newsDataProvider: NewsDataProvider) : NewsService {

    override fun loadNews(): Observable<Result> {

         return Observable.just(newsDataProvider.fetchData())

    }
}
```

Inside NewsDataProvider is normal sync retrofit call.

Problem is, that from every begininning useCase is invoked in the mainThread(). Shouldn't be called in a new thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
Observable.just(foo)
```

with something like

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> foo)
```

`Observable.just()` creates an observable from the supplied values and you're computing the value on the main thread. `fromCallable()` takes in a callback that can be invoked on your subscription thread.

Comment: Yes. That was the case! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Make `fetchData` return an `Observable<Result>` (or potentially `Single` but that would require wider updates in your code).  `Retrofit` supports `RxJava`.